# GUI Design breaks when resizing the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I resize my web page window, it breaks the GUI design and tabs looks bad:

```
<TABLE border="0" bordercolor="red" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="homeContainer" >
---------------- here the rest of contents
</TABLE>
```

[image]

Comment: The image is rather small. Can you create a bigger one?

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." Doctor: "Don't do that then".

Comment: Are you using 'width' at all?

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me...at least it's still usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the rest of tables' width and CSS?

Comment: i.e. this probleam is occured due to table width.?

Comment: Absolutely. You don't want to wrap your side-menu when you resize window, rite? If so, assign "nowrap" into side-menu.